# Error 'class HotelRoom' has no member named 'menu' even though it is there

Tags: c++

I am attempting to build a hotel reservation program in C++. however, I have an issue. I keep getting the above error message and I can't seem to find a fix.

Please provide some assistance. Anything would be greatly appreciated. Below is what I have written thus far.

```
using namespace std;
class HotelRoom{
    private:
        int roomnum; //Room numbers
        int roomcap; //Room capacity
        int roomoccuoystst = 0;
        int maxperperroom;
        double dailyrate;
    public:
        HotelRoom()
        {
           roomcap = 0;
           maxperperroom = 2;
           dailyrate = 175;
        }

            int gettotal  = 0;
            int gettotallist  = 0;
            string room;
            string guestroom,message;




    void viewrooms()
    {
        char viewselect, back;
        cout<<"Which room list would you like to view ?. 1 - Add rooms, 2 - Reserved rooms : " ;
        cin>>viewselect;
        switch(viewselect)
        {
        case '1':
            viewaddromm();
            break;
        case '2':
            viewresromm();
            break;
        default:
            cout<<"Please select from the option provided or go back to the main menu. 1 - view rooms, 2 - to the mail menu or any other key to exit the program : ";
            cin>>back;
            switch(back)
            {
                case '1':
                    viewrooms();
                    break;
                case '2':
                    hotelmenu();
                    break;
                default:
                    exitpro();

            }
        }
    }

    void viewresromm()
    {
                int occup,rmchoose,up;
                string roomtochange, items;
                string guestroomdb;
                int newaccupancy;
                char decisionmade,savinf;
                string fname, lname, nationality;
                string checkaddroom;
                ifstream getdatafromaddroom; //creation of the ifstream object
                getdatafromaddroom.open("reserveroom.out");


                  if(getdatafromaddroom.fail()) //if statement used for error checking
                    {
                        cout<<"Could not open file"<<endl; //message that will be printed if the program cannot open the file
                    }

                                cout<<endl;
                                cout<<"First Name"<<'-'<<"Last Name"<<'-'<<"Nationality"<<'-'<<"Guest(s)"<<'-'<<"Room #"<<endl;
                                cout<<"-------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
                                string items;
                     while(!getdatafromaddroom.eof())
                            {

                           //     getdatafromaddroom >>fname>>lname>>nationality>>occup>>guestroomdb;
                           getline(getdatafromaddroom, items);
                               //cout<<setw(5)<<fname<<' '<<setw(10)<<lname<<' '<<setw(10)<<nationality<<' '<<setw(10)<<occup<<' '<<setw(9)<<guestroomdb<<endl;
                               gettotallist++;

                                      if( getdatafromaddroom.eof() ) break;
                                      cout<<items<<endl;
                            }

                                 for(int getlist = 0; getlist < gettotallist; getlist++ )
                                    {
                                        cout<<items<<endl;
                                       // cout<<setw(5)<<fname<<' '<<setw(10)<<lname<<' '<<setw(10)<<nationality<<' '<<setw(10)<<occup<<' '<<setw(9)<<guestroomdb<<endl;
                                    }
    }

    void viewaddromm()
    {
                int occup,rmchoose,up;
                string roomtochange;
                string guestroomdb;
                int newaccupancy;
                char decisionmade,savinf;
                string fname, lname, nationality;
                string checkaddroom;
                fstream getdatafromaddroom; //creation of the ifstream object
                getdatafromaddroom.open("addroom.out");


                 if(getdatafromaddroom.fail()) //if statement used for error checking
                    {
                        cout<<"Could not open file"<<endl; //message that will be printed if the program cannot open the file
                    }

                                cout<<endl;
                                cout<<"First Name"<<'-'<<"Last Name"<<'-'<<"Nationality"<<'-'<<"Guest(s)"<<'-'<<"Room #"<<endl;
                                cout<<"-------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
                                string items;
                     while(!getdatafromaddroom.eof())
                            {

                           //     getdatafromaddroom >>fname>>lname>>nationality>>occup>>guestroomdb;
                           getline(getdatafromaddroom, items);
                               //cout<<setw(5)<<fname<<' '<<setw(10)<<lname<<' '<<setw(10)<<nationality<<' '<<setw(10)<<occup<<' '<<setw(9)<<guestroomdb<<endl;
                               gettotallist++;

                                      if( getdatafromaddroom.eof() ) break;
                                      cout<<items<<endl;
                            }

                                 for(int getlist = 0; getlist < gettotallist; getlist++ )
                                    {
                                        cout<<items<<endl;
                                       // cout<<setw(5)<<fname<<' '<<setw(10)<<lname<<' '<<setw(10)<<nationality<<' '<<setw(10)<<occup<<' '<<setw(9)<<guestroomdb<<endl;
                                    }



    }

    void exitpro()
    {
        cout<<"Program closing......Goodbye"<<endl;
        system("Pause");
        exit(0);
    }

    menu()
    {
        char menuchoice;
         cout<<"[-------------------------------------------------------]"<<endl;
        cout<<"[-Welcome to the hotel booking and reseration menu-]"<<endl;
        cout<<"[--------------------------------------------------------]"<<endl;

        cout<<setw(30)<<"Addroom -- 1"<<endl;
        cout<<setw(32)<<"Reserve a room -- 2"<<endl;
        cout<<setw(34)<<" Modify a room -- 3"<<endl;
        cout<<setw(36)<<"View roms -- 4"<<endl;
        cout<<setw(38)<<" Exist -- 5"<<endl;
        cin>>menuchoice;
        switch(menuchoice)
        {
        case '1':
            Addroom();
            break;
        case '2':
            reserveroom();
            break;
        case '3':
            modifyroom();
            break;
        case '4':
            viewrooms();
            break;
        }
    }
};

#endif
```

Comment: Aren't you forgetting something for the `menu` function? What does it *return*?

Comment: Please read about [mcve]. You dont need all the other methods to get an error about the missing `menu` member

Comment: Also, please learn how to create a [***Minimal***, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). When asking about build errors, *always* include the actual errors you get. Copy-pasted as text, in full and complete.

Comment: Your `HotelRoom` is more a `Hotel` instead a `Room`. Calling `exit()` is a no-no in a C++-program.

Comment: I get a lot of other errors. `Addroom` isn't defined, and neither is `hotelmenu`, `modifyroom` or `reserveroom`.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback thanks.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;
class HotelRoom
{
  private:
    int roomnum;                // Room numbers
    int roomcap;                // Room capacity
    int roomoccuoystst = 0;
    int maxperperroom;
    double dailyrate;
  public:


      HotelRoom()
    {
        roomcap = 0;
        maxperperroom = 2;
        dailyrate = 175;
    }

    int gettotal = 0;
    int gettotallist = 0;
    string room;
    string guestroom, message;




    void viewrooms()
    {
        char viewselect, back;
        cout << "Which room list would you like to view ?. 1 - Add rooms, 2 - Reserved rooms : ";
        cin >> viewselect;
        switch (viewselect)
        {
        case '1':
            viewaddromm();
            break;
        case '2':
            viewresromm();
            break;
        default:
            cout <<
                "Please select from the option provided or go back to the main menu. 1 - view rooms, 2 - to the mail menu or any other key to exit the program : ";
            cin >> back;
            switch (back)
            {
            case '1':
                viewrooms();
                break;
            case '2':
                 menu();
                break;
            default:
                exitpro();

            }
        }
    }

    void viewresromm()
    {

        string roomtochange, items;
        string guestroomdb;
        // int newaccupancy;
        // char decisionmade,savinf;
        string fname, lname, nationality;
        string checkaddroom;
        ifstream getdatafromaddroom;    // creation of the ifstream object
        getdatafromaddroom.open("reserveroom.out");


        if (getdatafromaddroom.fail())  // if statement used for error
                                        // checking
        {
            cout << "Could not open file" << endl;  // message that will be
                                                    // printed if the program
                                                    // cannot open the file
                                                    return;
        }

        cout << endl;
        cout << "First Name" << '-' << "Last Name" << '-' << "Nationality" << '-' << "Guest(s)" <<
            '-' << "Room #" << endl;
        cout << "-------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
        // string items;
        while (!getdatafromaddroom.eof())
        {

            // getdatafromaddroom
            // >>fname>>lname>>nationality>>occup>>guestroomdb;
            getline(getdatafromaddroom, items);
            // cout<<setw(5)<<fname<<' '<<setw(10)<<lname<<'
            // '<<setw(10)<<nationality<<' '<<setw(10)<<occup<<'
            // '<<setw(9)<<guestroomdb<<endl;
            gettotallist++;

            if (getdatafromaddroom.eof())
                break;
            cout << items << endl;
        }

        for (int getlist = 0; getlist < gettotallist; getlist++)
        {
            cout << items << endl;
            // cout<<setw(5)<<fname<<' '<<setw(10)<<lname<<'
            // '<<setw(10)<<nationality<<' '<<setw(10)<<occup<<'
            // '<<setw(9)<<guestroomdb<<endl;
        }
    }

    void viewaddromm()
    {
        // int occup,rmchoose,up;
        string roomtochange;
        string guestroomdb;
        // int newaccupancy;
        // char decisionmade,savinf;
        string fname, lname, nationality;
        string checkaddroom;
        fstream getdatafromaddroom; // creation of the ifstream object
        getdatafromaddroom.open("addroom.out");


        if (getdatafromaddroom.fail())  // if statement used for error
                                        // checking
        {
            cout << "Could not open file" << endl;  // message that will be
                                                    // printed if the program
                                                    // cannot open the file
                                                    return;
        }

        cout << endl;
        cout << "First Name" << '-' << "Last Name" << '-' << "Nationality" << '-' << "Guest(s)" <<
            '-' << "Room #" << endl;
        cout << "-------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
        string items;
        while (!getdatafromaddroom.eof())
        {

            // getdatafromaddroom
            // >>fname>>lname>>nationality>>occup>>guestroomdb;
            getline(getdatafromaddroom, items);
            // cout<<setw(5)<<fname<<' '<<setw(10)<<lname<<'
            // '<<setw(10)<<nationality<<' '<<setw(10)<<occup<<'
            // '<<setw(9)<<guestroomdb<<endl;
            gettotallist++;

            if (getdatafromaddroom.eof())
                break;
            cout << items << endl;
        }

        for (int getlist = 0; getlist < gettotallist; getlist++)
        {
            cout << items << endl;
            // cout<<setw(5)<<fname<<' '<<setw(10)<<lname<<'
            // '<<setw(10)<<nationality<<' '<<setw(10)<<occup<<'
            // '<<setw(9)<<guestroomdb<<endl;
        }



    }

    void exitpro()
    {
        cout << "Program closing......Goodbye" << endl;
    //  system("Pause");
        exit(0);
    }

    void Addroom()
    {
        std::string mess = __func__;
        mess += " is not yet implimented.";
        throw new std::logic_error(mess.c_str());
    }

    void reserveroom()
    {
        std::string mess = __func__;
        mess += " is not yet implimented.";
        throw new std::logic_error(mess.c_str());
    }

    void modifyroom()
    {
        std::string mess = __func__;
        mess += " is not yet implimented.";
        throw new std::logic_error(mess.c_str());
    }

    void menu()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            char menuchoice;
            cout << "[-------------------------------------------------------]" << endl;
            cout << "[-Welcome to the hotel booking and reseration menu-]" << endl;
            cout << "[--------------------------------------------------------]" << endl;

            cout << setw(30) << "Addroom -- 1" << endl;
            cout << setw(30) << "Reserve a room -- 2" << endl;
            cout << setw(30) << "Modify a room -- 3" << endl;
            cout << setw(30) << "View rooms -- 4" << endl;
            cout << setw(30) << "Exit -- 5" << endl;
            cin >> menuchoice;
            switch (menuchoice)
            {
            case '1':
                Addroom();
                break;
            case '2':
                reserveroom();
                break;
            case '3':
                modifyroom();
                break;
            case '4':
                viewrooms();
                break;
            case '5':
                exitpro();
            }
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        HotelRoom room;
        room.menu();
    }
    catch(std::logic_error * ex)
    {
        std::cout << ex->what();
    }

}
```

you have a lot more to go with this project. I've fixed the portion you specifically asked about and its now a runninng application with somewhat approperate diagnostics. I'm not going to get too deep into how this language works but you have several functions that were not implimented, missing return types, and just general logic errors like trying to use a file after you determined it wasnt open. it runs now, and you can get a clear indication of what you need to complete. You also had several unused varables.

i added , at minimal,

```
void Addroom()
    {
        std::string mess = __func__;
        mess += " is not yet implimented.";
        throw new std::logic_error(mess.c_str());
    }

    void reserveroom()
    {
        std::string mess = __func__;
        mess += " is not yet implimented.";
        throw new std::logic_error(mess.c_str());
    }

    void modifyroom()
    {
        std::string mess = __func__;
        mess += " is not yet implimented.";
        throw new std::logic_error(mess.c_str());


    }
```

and a return type to menu.
`void menu()

you cannot call functions you have not yet written, and all functions have a return type even if they return nothing.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi, can you highlight the major changes you made, each along with a brief explanation or in-code comment? It's difficult to go through all the code looking for "what mistake I made" or "where I could improve on". Thanks!

Comment: To add, I only get this error when I am using dev c++,  and the 3 functions you are referring to were implemented.
    Addroom()
    void reserveroom()
    void modifyroom()

Comment: Dray Mck they were not in the sample in your question. Read the comments on your post I'm not the only person that noticed that

Comment: Thats what  I am saying. The program is a lot. . i should have removed the ones i didnt include in the question .if you want me to send the entire file i could

Comment: Dray Mck sure just give me an ideone.com link

Comment: So all you have to do is to include the header file and create the object in  main .

Comment: i changed a few a small logic errors where you were trying to read a file that was not open, tidyed up some spelling errors, and gave it a whirl after getting past all the unused variables. set your compiler to -Wall to catch all of those warnings. Your on the right path and you don't have much left to complete. that ideone should compile on any compiler after you remove the main. i believe your question was just an issue with your developlment enviroment not having a clean project. I'll keep the file open if you have any more questions I'm happy to help. Run a diff on it for the changes.